# ember.js 1.0 bind controller to controller

Tags: ember.js

or else bind controller to two different views.

I'm doing this so my `'home'`  view gets the `PostsController` 's content.. but I need the real way to do it, if you can help me please!

```
HomeController: Ember.ArrayController.extend({    
     init: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
           App.router
             .get('homeController')
               .set('content', App.router.get('postsController').get('content'));
           }, 0);
        }

})
```

(using last version at this time **SHA: 83542a6**)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but if you give a jsFiddle your question will be much more likely to get help/discussion.  Don't expect others to do so much work to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question. What's wrong with the solution below?  [(original jsFiddle here)](http://jsfiddle.net/quant/q4Tbt/9/)  [(updated jsFiddle here)](http://jsfiddle.net/quant/q4Tbt/)

**(UPDATED: Added skeleton router)**

**JavaScript / Ember:**

```
// Application
App = Ember.Application.create({
    ApplicationController: Ember.Controller.extend(),
    ApplicationView: Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: "application-view",
    }),
    Router: Ember.Router.extend({
        // initialState of Ember.Router is "root"
        root: Ember.Route.extend({
            // "index" can be called whatever we want
            index: Ember.Route.extend({
                route: '/',
                enter: function(router) {
                    console.log("entering root.index from", router.get('currentState.name'));
                },
                connectOutlets: function(router) {
                    console.log("entered root.index, fully transitioned to", router.get('currentState.path'));
                    // Demo: read and write from router's connectOutlets
                    console.log("Router says, A:", App.get("aController").get('content'));
                    console.log("Router says, B:", App.get("bController").get('content'));
                    App.get("aController").pushObject({name: "Network switch", color: "beige", type: "Cisco"});
                    console.log("Router says, A:", App.get("aController").get('content'));
                    console.log("Router says, B:", App.get("bController").get('content'));
                }
            })
            // ... 
            // (add routes here)
            // ...
        })
    })
});

// Controllers
App.aController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    addContact: function(contact) {
        this.content.push(contact);
    }
});

App.bController = Ember.Object.create({
    contentBinding: "App.aController.content"
});

// Demo: Change a (shows up in b)
App.aController.set('content', [
    {name: "Apple", color: "red", type: "fruit"},
    {name: "Banana", color: "yellow", type: "fruit"},
    {name: "Sports car", color: "black", type: "vehicle"},
    {name: "Sun", color: "white", type: "star"},
     ]);

// Demo: Change b (shows up in a)
(function() {
    var temp = App.aController.get('content');
    temp.push({name: "Linus", color: "n/a", type: "human"});    
    App.bController.set('content', temp);
})();
```

**HTML / Handlebars:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application-view">
<div id="my-app">
<h1>aController</h1>
{{#collection tagName="ul" contentBinding="App.aController.content"}}
    {{#with view.content}}
        Name: {{name}}, Color: {{color}}, Type: {{type}},
    {{/with}}
{{/collection}}
<h1>bController</h1>
{{#collection tagName="ul" contentBinding="App.bController.content"}}
    {{#with view.content}}
        Name: {{name}}, Color: {{color}}, Type: {{type}},
    {{/with}}
{{/collection}}
</div>
</script>
```

Comment: @Tati, you need to provide more details. What is your use case? It's possible that the problem you're trying to solve is not intended to be solved the way you're trying to do it.

Comment: Please fix your console errors first. (the above link yields: Uncaught Error: <App.Router:ember412> could not respond to event doPost in state root.home.) Also, please move your links to your original posts so it is more obvious to people when they read your question.

Comment: Thanks! I guess my 'special' problem is I'm calling the controllers through the routers connectOutlets, and when I try to do that same binding you've done OUTSIDE the router, it doesn't work.. Now I've seen how to at least put everything in the same place (in the call from connectOutlets) http://jsfiddle.net/tatiana/MpKdq/2/

Comment: I've cleaned up the fiddle and it's working... (the link again is: http://jsfiddle.net/tatiana/MpKdq/9/) the content gets supplied through method in the router though.. still wondering how to get the same effect working with the view. Thanks for your time in any case!

Comment: So you want to set the content from the view instead of from the router's init?

Comment: Perhaps you could use connectControllers() ??
http://www.cloudee.com/go#/c/504a311f8ad6c2634f00002f (near 15:00)
http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/08/23/architecting-ember-js-apps/ (slide 31)

Comment: nice! slide 40 actually says "views: use with a single controller. If you need data from elsewhere, bring it into this vies's controller using connectControllers()" I'm checking into that, as well as your updated fiddle. Thanks again

Comment: I have reformulated my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799293/ember-js-connectcontrollers