# ember.js connectControllers()

Tags: ember.js

If you have 2 different pages (call them home and posts) that share ALMOST exactly the same content and functionality, how is the best way to bind one to the other?

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tatiana/UmHRf/1/) I have associated the content of one view to the content of the other by setting it directly in the router like this:

```
Router: Ember.Router.extend({
 root: Ember.Route.extend({

     //transitions 

      home: Ember.Route.extend({
          route: '/',
          connectOutlets: function(router) {    
               var posts = router.get('postsController.content');                              
               router.get('homeController').set('content', posts);
               router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('home');
          },
      }),

    //posts and other states
  })
})
```

But: I don't really need the home content to update on the fly if the posts content does, but if I did, would it?

What other way is there? Is it possible to use connectControllers() and then WHERE should it be used? Here is my -failed- attempt: [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tatiana/R635J/3/)

```
home: Ember.Route.extend({
     route: '/',
     connectOutlets: function(router) {                                            
         router.get('homeController').connectControllers('posts');                          
         router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('home');
      },                    
})
```

Comment: your attempt with connectControllers is almost good, you only have to see that the context of the homeView is the homeController. When connecting the postsController to the homeController, you don't not automatically connect it's content. So in the 'home' template you only have to replace `content` by `postsController`. see: http://jsfiddle.net/R635J/4/

Comment: @sly7_7 thanks, great! Can't mark your comment as the accepted answer though..

Comment: Seeing your example, I think the answer of @MikeAski should be the right one. (as the context is the same, and the view to). You would use connectControllers if you would share data between controllers.

Comment: @sly7_7 am checking. Gotta practice my question formulation a lot. Your comment answers directly my question 'Is it possible to use connectControllers()..' + title of the question = 'ember.js connectControllers()'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `template` helper.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts">
  <div class="right"><h2>posts page</h2>
    {{template "posts-details"}}
  </div>            
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts-details">
  {{#each post in content}} 
    <article>                                   
      <h3><a {{action "doPost" context="post"}} {{bindAttr id="post.id"}}>{{post.title}}</a></h3>
      <p>{{post.date}}</p>
    </article>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

See your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/UmHRf/3/)

Comment: It's almost working, but here there is a "home page" h2 in the posts page.

Comment: Updated fiddle & answer... Thx @sly7_7! :-)

Comment: Cool, I've never used that helper before. Is the main difference between {{template "my-template"}} and {{view Ember.View templateName="my-template"}} that {{template}} doesn't generate another ember view object?

Comment: That's it. No Ember.View is needed in this case, as there is no specific handler, computed property and so on.

Comment: You can consider it as 'template-inlining'

Comment: Glad I could help. You did not accept the answer, do you need further information?

Comment: @MikeAski your answer is correct and my question isn't, I should have said the layouts are almost the same, the content for the layouts -the array of posts- has to be EXACTLY the same therefore need either just one controller, or else they are binded someway. Sorry people, it's the lack of experience talking/sharing these things

Comment: Your welcome, no problem. The problem is: if you use `connectControllers` in `home`, you will have to iterate over `postsController`, but in `posts.index`, you would have to iterate over `content`... A _(not really clean)_ way out would be to iterate over `controllers.postsController` in the template, and avoid any binding.

Comment: @MikeAski it's an idea, at least it would leave clear the fact that the content IS coming from postsController in both cases -home and view- But say the home layout shows first post different then posts view does: http://jsfiddle.net/tatiana/92b7V/1/, then the template helper would have to know which view called it..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17815/discussion-between-mike-aski-and-tati)