# After Ember.Application.create: addressing the created instances of controllers/routers/views etc

Tags: ember.js

After a

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create
```

how can I address the automatically created instances of the router, controllers? I've found several posts stating that a

```
 App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend ...
```

should result in an instantiated

```
 App.loginController
```

on the app - but this does no longer seem to be the case with 1.0.0-PRE.4.

I tried several things like

```
 App.router // undefined
 App.get("router") // undefined
 App.get("router.loginController") // undefined
 App.get("router.login") // undefined
 App.get("loginController") // undefined
 ...
```

but nothing seems to work.

```
 App.defaultRouter()
```

is actually a function that creates a new, empty router: but not the one I defined using

```
 App.Router.map (match)->
     ...
```

I'm trying to get a handle to look into the running app in chrome, and also need to pass in a variable into a controller from an asynchronous running call outside ember (a facebook lookup to check if the user is already logged in) - so any hint how I can peek&poke into ember from outside is more than welcome!!

PS: And please can somebody create the version-tags for ember: With all the API-changes, the most difficult thing for a newbie is currently to find out if an answer actually applies to the current version of ember or if it is already outdated: A tag indicating in which version the answer actually works would be really helpful ...

Answer (score 2):

With Ember pre-4 the instances are no longer placed on App.loginController etc. I think these were only placed there for debug/test purposes and was not to be used in production code. These are now placed in

```
App.__container__
```

And as the name indicates, dont use it. It's superprivate. :)

As of pre-4 rendering templates/views, setting up controllers and defining model/content of controllers is to be setup in routes. You can read about it in the guides http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/

When it comes to your question about integration with facebook you can use the Ember.Instrumentation namespace to subscribe and fire events to your app from outside. You can see the question and answer here: [How to fire an event to Ember from another framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458287/how-to-fire-an-event-to-ember-from-another-framework)

Comment: thx, that was helpful! Concerning the router, I found it at App.Router.router - don't know, if it is only private or super private :) - but there at least some methods like transitionTo that could be useful on the router for outside access...

Comment: If you need to transitionTo you can do that from a controller by calling controller.transitionTo('routeName'). Or you can send a event that bubbles through you routes with controller.send('eventName') and handle it in the respective route. IMO sending an event that bubbles to your router is the best way to do this, so that the controller has responsability for the model while the routes have the responsability of routing.

Comment: And thx for Ember.Instrumentation.instrument! - this rocks! Definitely the way to go to hook into ember from outside without the need to expose too much of the internals.

Comment: np, did it answer your questing properly?