# How do you load data into Ember Data from a Socket.IO response?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, socket.io, ember-data

I'm writing an app which leverages Ember.js, with Ember Data, and Socket.IO through Node.js.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to receive data from a socket response and load it into my Ember Data store, such as this:

```
window.socket = io.connect('http://localhost');

socket.on('action here', function(response) {
  // how to load "response" JSON data into Ember Data store from here...?
});
```

Is the best (or only good) solution to write a custom DS.Adapter?  Or is there another good, maintainable way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, I ended up going with the answer proposed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14508316/1470194

Using that Ember.Instrumentation technique, I was able to facilitate calls to my controllers and access my store that way.

I realize that writing a custom adaptor may be necessary in many case, but it was beyond the required scope of my project, so this solution ended up being perfect.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to write your own adaptor, but if you only need to load models(no save) you can get away with the adaptor's `load` method - something like this:

```
socket.on('single-model', function(response) {
    DS.defaultStore.load(response);
});

socket.on('multiple-models', function(response) {
    for(i in response){
        DS.defaultStore.load(response[i]);
    }
});
```

Define the adaptor as `FixtureAdaptor`.