# Incrementally adding models to controller

Tags: ember.js

I have a standard issue route like:

```
App.MessagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function() {
        return App.Message.find();
    }

});
```

Which works great for the existing set of messages that i get from a REST endpoint.   But I also get new messages via a websocket.   How in the RC2 routing architecture (and non-Ember Data store) how do I plumb new message like these into Ember cleanly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using the Ember.Instrumentation framework element that's talked about in [How to fire an event to Ember from another framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458287/how-to-fire-an-event-to-ember-from-another-framework/14508316#14508316).

Here's my complete code:

```
...
// this is fired from my websocket message reception code.

Ember.Instrumentation.instrument('onMessage', message);
...

App.MessagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        Ember.Instrumentation.subscribe('onMessage', {
            before: function(name, timestamp, message) {
                controller.send('onMessage', message);
            },
            after: function() {}
        });
    },

    model: function() {
        return App.Message.find();
    }

});


App.MessagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    onMessage: function(message) {
        this.unshiftObject(message);
    }
});
```