# Custom Services In Ember

Tags: ember.js

I am looking to have some polling going on in my ember js app.

I currently have some code in ApplicationController in the init method.

I feel that the code should really be moved off into some service object, but if I do that, I will lose all the hooks that I get as I am no longer in the ApplicationController.

What is the best practice to include such code?

Should I create an ember object that deals with it, that has a reference back to the ApplicationController?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I feel that the code should really be moved off into some service object, but if I do that, I will lose all the hooks that I get as I am no longer in the ApplicationController. What is the best practice to include such code?

Your right, generally the best practice is to move this type of code into a service object.

> Should I create an ember object that deals with it, that has a reference back to the ApplicationController?

That is a solid approach, and would be a good first step. Beyone that you might consider using `Ember.Instrumentation` to decouple the polling mechanism from your application.

[How to fire an event to Ember from another framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458287/how-to-fire-an-event-to-ember-from-another-framework)

Comment: Cheers, the Instumentation is a perfect solution!