# Ember Controllers and Events from Third Party Libraries

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember application where I have integrated in several third party libraries, specifically one that handles signalling (from other peers).  My question is, what is the best way to update my controller objects based on external events from the third party libraries?  There are a few cases where I'm using Ember.deferred (promises) to capture a response from some of the libraries; however, I need a way to handle all events that are triggered in the libraries and to update my controllers accordingly.

Could someone provide me with a best-practice recommendation?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458287/how-to-fire-an-event-to-ember-from-another-framework

Comment: The solution works great if I handle it at the application level (ApplicationRoute and ApplicationController), but I have not been able to get it to work in another route/controller.  What do I need to add in order to get it to work with something other than Application?